# In Samusung Device facing crash on launching other App

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-manifest, samsung-mobile, android-launcher

I am trying to launch an application from another app but I am facing crash as "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException" in Samsung Device , In my use case I am having two App as
**App A** and **App B** , From **App A** I am trying to launch **App B** but I am facing crash as exception
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.wallstreetenglish.dc.row cmp=com.repo.row/lib.repo.activity.SplashActivity }

Unable to find explicit activity class {com.repo.row/lib.repo.activity.SplashActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?

I have used the code as

```
appIntent?.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            val activityId = Uri.parse(respUrl).getQueryParameter("activityId")
            Session.preferences.accessToken.let {
                val constructedUrl = "launch-app://open?userId=" + SharedContext.ssdsRefId + "&activityId=" + activityId + "&authorization=" + it
                appIntent?.data = Uri.parse(constructedUrl)
                context.startActivity(appIntent)
            }
```

In the activity B I have added the intent filter for splash activity as below

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppNoActionBarTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="launch-app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Device Info : Samsung - Android version 13